# GitHub showing incorrect head commit

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-api

A colleague and I have come across what seems to be an odd GitHub anomaly and can't seem to figure out or understand it.

**Background**

We have an app that makes commits to a GitHub repo with pieces of text we use in a large comparison engine. We only work on the master branch. We don't use any other branches.

**Issue**

When accessing the repo through GitHub, the latest commit is shown as XXXXXX (for the purposes of this discussion). An error returned by the application we've developed picked up that the HEAD commit wasn't as expected, and when running

```
git log
```

commit YYYYYY is shown to be HEAD.
Commit YYYYYY does not show in the GitHub commit log, but when injected into the github commit viewing URL, it shows the commit.

The two commits have the same commit time.

**Questions**

1. Has anyone experienced this before?
2. What would cause such behavior?

**Resolution**

We made an additional commit afterwards to change the HEAD, but commit YYYYYY still does not show in the GitHub UI :(

Comment: @sajibkahn - The local commits were pushed - as i mentioned, if you inject the commit hash into the GitHub commit viewer URL, you can view it.

Comment: Who force pushed?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Haha - A forcepush was not done, as the commit was done by the system we're working on.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the commit histories in github by this way:

github -> Graphs tab -> Network.

Check the commit id orders, it should same with `git log`.

Or you can use `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` for further analyze.

In local repo, you use `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`, the HEAD is point to YYYYYY. Please **check the parent** (commit id before YYYYYY) is XXXXXX or not.

If it’s parent is XXXXXX, it means the local commit YYYYYY is not pushed to github.

If it’s parent is not XXXXXX but ZZZZZZ. Now you need to check on github, if the XXXXXX’s parent is ZZZZZZ. If this is the situation, that means when you push XXXXXX and YYYYYY to github nearly same time, but one of them failed. The structure like:

```
A---B---…---Z---X
             \
              Y
```

Comment: Hey @Marina, the commit was missing from this list, and unfortunately I can't mark this as the resolving answer to my question

Comment: I updated my answer for further analysis, you can find it out by the way.

Comment: @N15M0_jk, did the answer help you solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @Marina, it still doesn't correctly explain the issue I was having - you mentioned "it means the local commit YYYYYY is not pushed to github", although I state in my explanation that when I inject the commit hash into the github commit URL, it appears. Regarding the parenting I can't check anymore as I've since resolved the issue by doing minor commits afterwards which then showed the missing commit in the github commit log.